# Maximum number of referenced methods per dex file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

My app contains much more than 64k referenced methods so I'm using multidex to create dex files:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
      ...
      multiDexEnabled true
  }

  dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries false
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

I have it configured correctly and dex files are created but I am wondering is there a way to limit maximum number of referenced methods per dex file? I have Android 19 set as a minimum version.

My main dex file is only a couple of methods away from maximum of 65,536 methods so I would like to lower this number to ~60k methods. Using ProGuard is not an option at the moment.

Comment: sir do u have application class ?

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki, I have. It's extending MultiDexApplication.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any google play services, include only those API's that you need instead of the complete google-play-services. For example if you use admob ads add the dependency

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'`

instead of including the complete play services library like `'compile com.google.android.gms:play:9.0.0'`. This will reduce your dex size.

Comment: Thank you but I'll be still far away. Too many libraries and methods :)